# import data from dataset to livecyle designer table

Tags: adobe, designer, livecycle

I have created pdf template using livecycle designer. I have a table with name table in the pdf template.  I am able to fill the rest of the all the text fields with the data from the dataset, but unable to fill the table with the data.  I have sotred the data from the data set in a string variable.  I can see the respective values in the string variable, but unable to pass the data to the table.

Here is the code that able to pass the data to text fileds:
string ref_name1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["REF_NAME"].ToString();
 form.SetField("REF_NAME1[0]", ref_name1);

I tried similar way  to pass the info to the table, some how it is not recognizing the table.

Any help....Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't bind data directly to the table? 
In the object -> binding tab ([see here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/DesignerQuickStartTutorials/images/fl_binding_row1_popup.png)) you can select the data connection. And make sure the "Repeat Row for each Data Item" is selected.